# What's the dimension of the span of fixed-frequency plane waves in $H^1$ of a domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, exponential-function, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact domain such that its first Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$ embeds compactly into $L^2(\Omega)$. (It is sufficient that $\partial\Omega$ be Lipschitz.)

For $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^d$, define $e_\omega:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ by $e_\omega(x) = \exp( i\omega\cdot x )$. Notice that $e_\omega\in H^1(\Omega)$, with gradient $\nabla e_\omega = i\omega e_\omega$.

### Question

> What is the dimension of the subspace $S(\mu) = \operatorname{span} \{ e_\omega\ |\ |\omega|^2 = \mu\}$ in $H^1(\Omega)$?

### Thoughts

The Neumann Laplacian has discrete spectrum $0 = \mu_1\leq\mu_2\leq\cdots $ (counted with multiplicity). Set $N(\mu) = \# \{k\ |\ \mu_k \leq \mu\}$.

These eigenvalues satisfy the min-max property:
$$ \mu_k = \min_E \max_{u\in E} \frac{\int |\nabla u|^2\ dx}{\int |u|^2\ dx}$$
where $E$ ranges over all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $H^1(\Omega)$. The ratio $R(u) = \int |\nabla u|^2 / \int |u|^2$ is known as the Rayleigh quotient.

In particular any subspace of $H^1$ with dimension greater than $k$ has at least one element with Rayleigh quotient no less than $\mu_{k+1}$. Equivalently if every element of a subspace has Rayleigh quotient at most $\mu_k$, then the dimension of the subspace is no greater than $k$.

As $R(e_\omega) = |\omega|^2$, we must have $\operatorname{dim} S(\mu) \leq N(\mu)$. So there must be an inordinate amount of linear dependencies among the $e_\omega$.

But at the same time, suppose a linear combination of the $e_\omega$ vanish, say $\sum c_k e_{\omega_k} = 0$ on $\Omega$. Because the $e_\omega$ are all bounded, the sum $\sum c_k \exp(i\omega_k x)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and as an analytic function equal to zero on an open set, must have all $c_k = 0$.

This seems like a contradiction. What am I missing? Are there any known approaches to the question?

Comment: There are infinitely many $\omega\in{\mathbb R}^d$ with $|\omega|^2=\mu$ if $d>1$. Since none of the $e_\omega$ are linearly dependent, the dimension of $S(\mu)$ is infinity.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth that contradicts the min-max principle does it not? If $\mu_k > \mu$ there cannot be a $k+1$ dimensional subspace $E$ of $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\max_{u\in E} R(u) = \mu < \mu_k$.

Comment: I fail to see the connection between the $\mu$ you use in the definition of $S(\mu)$ and the $\mu$ you use in the definition of $N(\mu)$. These are distinct objects, and so I do not believe that there ought to be a relationship between the dimension of $S(\mu)$ and $N(\mu)$.

Comment: In other words, just because you use the same symbol in two places means that they should be the same. You could have used $a$ in the definition of $S(a)$.

Comment: means -> does not mean